# How to find the critical points, jacobian matrix and eigen values in python for a set of autonomous equations ? How to get their phase space plot?

Tags: python

I'm new to python. i have a set of autonomous equation, trying to analyse the asymptotic behaviour using phase space analysis.

```
f(x,y)=a*x*y((y**2)+a+c)
g(x,y)=a+(y**3)+((y**3)+(y**2)(x+a))
```

where `x`and `y` are the variables ? i seek help to find the critical points, jacobian and eigen values, also to get the phase space plot ?

Comment: Do you want to do this numerically, or symbolically?  Just how new are you to Python?  new to programming?  math?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [symPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) Library. 
It has a built in symbolic solver for Jacobians.

- You can use the `Eq` method to solve for your *critical points*.
- Use the `eigenvals` method to find the eigenvals of your Jacobian.
- Lastly you can employ the `quiver` module from [Scipy](https://www.scipy.org/) along with [pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) to plot your phase space plot. Good luck.

Comment: Could you please share the steps for above problem, as an example ?